# How can I separate two columns of count by group by?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

When I do this,

```
SELECT id, gender, count(1)
FROM class_student
WHERE id = 1
GROUP BY gender
```

I get

```
id  gender    count
--------------------
1   female    10
1   male      5
```

How can I get this?

```
id female male
---------------
1  10     5
```

Is following query is the right way to do this?

```
SELECT
    id,
    (select count(1) from class_student
     where id = 1 AND gender='female') AS female,
    (select count(1) from class_student
     where id = 1 AND gender='male') AS male
FROM class_student
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12005676/5079380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a  select with case when

```
  SELECT id
         , sum(case when gender = 'male' then 1 else 0 end) male, 
         , sum(case when gender = 'female' then 1 else 0 end) female
    FROM class_student
    WHERE id = 1
    GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `GROUP BY id`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CASES**:

```
SELECT id, SUM(case when gender = 'male' then 1 else 0 end) male, SUM(case when gender = 'female' then 1 else 0 end) female
    FROM CLASS_STUDENT
    WHERE id = 1
    GROUP BY id;
```